# Clear Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a web socket that accepts an object called PushMessage and sends it to a React page, which subsequently updates in real-time. The way this works is that the user searches for the PushMessage he wishes to display, and this is then passed in. However, what happens right now is that if the user searches for the first PushMessage, that one is displayed, but if he or she then searches for another PushMessage, both of them are displayed. I would like to only display the second of them. In order to do this I feel like I need to clear the Redux store (return it to its initial, empty state). However, I can't figure out how to do this.

My Reducer is given by:

```
var Redux = require('redux');
var _ = require('lodash');

var pushNotificationDefaultState = {};


var pushMessageReducer = function(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'RECEIVED_PUSH_MESSAGE':
            var obj = JSON.parse(action.PushMessage);
            return _.assign({}, state, obj);
        default:
            if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
                return pushNotificationDefaultState;
            }

            return state;
    }
};

module.exports = Redux.combineReducers({
    pushMessages: pushMessageReducer
});
```

In the component I have:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
}


var AppContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
)(App);
```

Any and all help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to clear the store.  Can you show your code for the reducer of PushMessage?

Comment: I've edited to add the reducer. Thanks.

Comment: @user5407287 You really should have a structure in you reducer's state, not just blindly pass the result of an action into it. The point of the reducer is to have a clear structure that smartly responds to actions, not just a place to dump action results.

Comment: You need to use your action creators and reducers to properly manage your applications state. If you want to only show the second item as you have said, that can either be business logic on the react component itself, or you can get a little more clever with how you are managing your state in your reducers.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding how to properly use React with Redux (I'm totally new to all of this). But, if everything is a PushMessage, then why would I have more than one part of my reducer? Isn't the only job of the reducer to reduce everything into the store? Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in a number of ways, I will show you how I would approach it. Let's look at your state right off the bat - because you are using combine reducers you are splitting your state like so :

```
{
  pushMessages: { pushMessages state in here }
}
```

So combineReducers is great when you want to split your app into kind of "substates", thought redux is still single store in this instance. Right now you just have the single substate of `pushMessages`.

I would take the component and set up an action to add a message to it (and maybe one to remove message eventually). I am using `immutable.js` because I happen to like working with it and IMO it makes redux nice to work with because the state should be immutable anyways (again, personal opinion).

So here are your reducers :

```
 var pushMessageReducer = function(state = immutable.Map(), action) {
    if (action && action.type) {
        switch (action.type) {

            case actions. RECEIVED_PUSH_MESSAGE:
                return state.update('messages', immutable.List(),
                    (oldMessages) => oldMessages.push(action.PushMessage)
                );


            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

So what this does is set your state up like so :

```
{
   pushMessages: {
      messages: [ ... all your messages pushed in here] 
   }
}
```

Because you are using combine reducers your container should be subscribed to it's substate of pushMessages, so in your component you will have `this.props.messages` with an array of your messages. (if you have not subscribed to the sub state its just `this.props.pushMessages.messages`. And to display the last item all you really need is something like this (this is using lodash, you can certainly do this in vanilla js or whatever you want)

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getLastMessage = this.getLastMessage.bind(this);
 }     

  getLastMessage() {
      return _.last(this.props.messages);
  }

  render() {

     return(
         <div>
           Last Message : {this.getLastMessage())
         </div>
     );
  }
```

So maybe you don't want the list to contain everything and only show the last one (I'm not sure what exact business logic you are looking for) but you can easily add an `REMOVE_PUSH_MESSAGE` action and just pop or splice from that array of messages. (and then you could just show this.props.message without the _.last). Hope this helps!

Edit:

Here is how I would set up your container:

```
import immutable from 'immutable';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Component from './component';
import * as actionCreators from './action-creators';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const normalizedState = state.get('pushMessageReducer', immutable.Map()).toJS();

    return {
        messages: normalizedState.messages
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        myAction: actionCreators.myAction.bind(null, dispatch)
    };
}


export default function(component = Component) {
    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
}
```

You'll notice the `normalizedState` in mapStateToProps, I use this to grab the section of the state I want to use in this container, unless your app only has 1 smart component then you probably wouldn't do this. It just grabs the part of the state (from immutable) that I am using in this container, in your case it's `pushMessages`. So now in this component you connected, you should have `this.props.messages` with your items. I also use `mapDispatchToProps` to bind in my actions, because it gives you dispatch in your action creators which makes async really easy.

With the combined code properly hooked up (I didn't know hooking up the action here), you should fire that `RECEIVED_PUSH_MESSAGE` action creator with a new message on `action.PushMessage`. This then connects to your mapStateToProps which updates `this.props.messages` on your component, which should only be rendering the last item in the list.

Comment: This is extremely helpful! Thanks so much! Just one thing is that using the code you gave, it doesn't seem to add the PushMessage to the list. It creates the map and treats the state as a map, but the map is always empty. Thanks again!

Comment: @user5407287 I don't really understand what you are saying here. The state is an object, but that messages section created inside the state is a list. If you connect this correctly to your redux store and state you will have the state set up as listed above. Just keep in mind this is somewhat psuedo code and im using immutable, but it should work. You might want to show how you are hooking up redux and the container also. Like how are you doing mapStateToProps for example?

Comment: I edited to include more code. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @user5407287 I updated the answer. Just a heads up - you absolutely do not need to use immutable, I just use it so it's faster for me to type examples out using it :)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that just because you receive many messages, you may never need more than the last one stored, which means saving a list may be overkill. If all you ever display is current data, then why store the entire history? So, instead of clearing the state, you can just do `case 'RECEIVED_PUSH_MESSAGE': return JSON.parse(action.PushMessage);` in your reducer. This would _replace_ the state (essentially clear + add, but better).

Comment: @DDS yes absolutely you can replace the current message, that is a great way of doing this. OP just has a list and wants to show last (Second as they put it) in their example. Don't know all their intended business logics so they may want the history of messages. Either way I would still split messages into it's own substate, but that's personal opinion of course!

Comment: I am still trying to fathom WHY we should use immutable.js IF using Redux - because the whole paradigm of redux is actionCreate -> Reducer -> UpdateState,,, and if you follow that -- your state should always be immutable. So, I am curious why bring in additional filesize, code, etc.... to do something that Redux, if followed correctly, will always do? Please let me know.

Comment: @jamesemanon you said it yourself, your state should always be immutable and it's not, hence immutablejs. Redux does not do this out of the box. IMO - react should be set up to work with it too, then things like the `pure-render-mixin` would become trivial because you don't need the deep comparison of state with immutable.